# Is there a JIRA mechanism that will notify users in-browser when a ticket changes?

Tags: jira

People often open a JIRA issue by URL, and then start working on it.
They have to manually refresh (usually after seeing an email notification) to see any changes to the ticket like edits to the description or new comments, or any other change for that matter by other users (or even themselves in a different window).

Similar to other agile boards, is there any mechanism to periodically check if a ticket has changed since the page was loaded? Examples might be  popup message or link to refresh the page.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace It's on the bubble. I'd be tempted to view this as a "how do I make a PM tool do X" question rather than a tool recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

Jira integrates well with [hipchat](https://www.hipchat.com/), and if you have set notifications on for a particular project, then when someone updates, or changes the state of a particular ticket, then there is a notification to that hipchat channel.

Further to this, [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) is a GIT solution that is integrated strongly into hipchat and jira.

Not sure if this answers your question, but I hope so, it depends on your way of working.

Declaration: I am not associated with Atlassian, but think their software is pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

Jira has recently released real-time notifications natively in the Jira UI. I only use Cloud so I can't speak for Server, but it's there now.